# How to set timeout for child threads in ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, multithreading

I would like to set a timeout for each child thread created with `executor.submit`.

I've tried the following solution, but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestion?

```
futures = []

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    for element in collection.find():
        future = executor.submit(function)
        futures.append(future)

for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
    try:
        future.result(timeout=300)
    except concurrent.futures.TimeoutError:
        print('timeout')
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [as_completed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.as_completed) gives an iterator that yields for the futures as "they are completed". I think what you are after is to call `future.result` by going back directly to the `futures` array (so that you are **not** waiting for them to be completed) and also before the executor is released:

```py
futures = []

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    for element in collection.find():
        future = executor.submit(function)
        futures.append(future)

    for future in futures:
        try:
            future.result(timeout=300)
        except concurrent.futures.TimeoutError:
            print('timeout')
            pass
```